# I cant enter second product name.I s there a problem with my while loop?

Tags: java, arraylist

This is my code and i am a beginner java programmer. I am trying to create a simple billing program.

```
    ArrayList<String> name=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Float> rate=new ArrayList<Float>();
    ArrayList<Float> quantity=new ArrayList<Float>();
    ArrayList<Float> price= new ArrayList<Float>();
    String name1;
    float rate1;
    float quantity1;
    float price1;
    boolean flag=true;
    int choice;
    float sum=0;
    while(flag)
    {
        System.out.println("ENTER PRODUCT NAME");
        name1=sc.nextLine();
        name.add(name1);
        
        System.out.println("ENTER RATE OF THE PRODUCT");
        rate1=sc.nextFloat();
        rate.add(rate1);
        System.out.println("ENTER QUANTITY OF THE PRODUCT");
         quantity1= sc.nextFloat();
        quantity.add(quantity1);
        
        price1=rate1*quantity1;
        price.add(price1);
        sum=sum+price1;
        
        System.out.println("IF YOU WANT TO ADD ANOTHER PRODUCT ENTER 1 OTHERWISE ENTER 0");
        choice=sc.nextInt();
        if(choice==1) {
            System.out.println('\f');
            flag=true;
        }
        else flag=false;
    }
```

But during the second while loop, i cant add the second product name, but i can add the remaining details like rate and price of second product. help me with this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Comment: yes thank you  . Used an empty next() methord and it worked